# Keeps getting NaN as result for jQuery AJAX copmuted value

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this HTML:

```
  <div id="URLs" style="display:block">
  <div>Insert New URL:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="NEW" value="" />
    <br/>Inserted URLs:
    <br/>
    <textarea id="direct_URLs" rows="0"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
  <input id="run" type="submit" value="Insert" />
```

And, I have this jQuery:

```
  $("#run").click(function () {
  if ($("#NEW").val() !== "") {
    $("#direct_URLs").append(($("#direct_URLs").val() == '' ? '' : "\n") + $("#NEW").val());
    $("#direct_URLs").attr('rows', function (i, val) {
      var cnt = parseInt(val, 10) || 0;
      return isNaN(cnt) ? 1 : cnt + 1;
    });
  }
  });
```

I keep getting `NaN` on the `rows=NaN`.

I've tried the and did setup the mentioned code in here: http://jsfiddle.net/s3GDr/1/ , and it's working just fine.
But, on my page.. it's ***NOT***..!! This drives me crazy, I've tried every thing I got my eyes on (Googled, other questions etc).
Please, some body shed some light on this..!! :(

Comment: Try maybe to change $("#run").click(function () { to $(document).on("click", "#run", function () {

Comment: What other code do you have on your page that isn't in your example?

Comment: @LouisXIV In the original page, the script is fired by `success:` function with a serial of commands, including both of those above.

Comment: @j08691 Is there a way I can send you a link on private ?!

Comment: Sorry, but SO doesn't have the functionality.